# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 17; columnNumber: 61; Attribute "value" must be declared for element type "property"

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2018)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:201)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1935)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1914)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:177)
    at com.isti.client.HibernateUtil.getAnnotationConfiguration(HibernateUtil.java:20)
    at com.isti.client.HibernateUtil.getUser(HibernateUtil.java:75)
    at com.isti.server.GreetingServiceImpl.getUser(GreetingServiceImpl.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
    ... 22 more!
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 17; columnNumber: 61; Attribute "value" must be declared for element type "property".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.addDTDDefaultAttrsAndValidate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2015)
    ... 37 more
```

Here's my `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<session-factory>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/LoginForm</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">public</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    <mapping class="com.isti.client.model.User" />

</session-factory>
```

Comment: I'd just listen to the message and add a `value` attribute. Have you tried that obvious approach already?

Comment: I've tried it now, and the problem is solved, thanks for your answers, and sorry for the question, but I'm new to hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
```

looks inconsistent ? In particular the absence of the `value` attribute doesn't look right.