# Attribute Value must be Declared for Element Type Property

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, orm

I've read: [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 17; columnNumber: 61; Attribute "value" must be declared for element type "property"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069549/org-xml-sax-saxparseexception-linenumber-17-columnnumber-61-attribute-valu) and I've added the value attribute on every tag, yet the Exception still occurs. This happens when I try to configure the hibernate configuration file from `Configuration.configure()` method.

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/team_db?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation" value="4"/>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="100"/>

    <!--Mappings-->
    <mapping class = "com.gmail.physicistsarah.test.TestObject"/>
</session-factory>
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2160)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2113)
at com.gmail.physicistsarah.library.core.HibernateMultiTool.getSessionFactory(HibernateMultiTool.java:103)
at com.gmail.physicistsarah.test.Init.main(Init.java:46)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 88; Attribute "value" must be declared for element type "property".
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.addDTDDefaultAttrsAndValidate(XMLDTDValidator.java:1253)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1917)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:763)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:356)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2157)
... 3 more
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **element property does not have an attribute value**

Try removing the value from the tag.

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
```

to

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
```

Also, the posted `cfg.xml` does not closes the `<hibernate-configuration>`, close this as well.

Comment: anyway, sometimes <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/> will have no problem, so under what circumstance above syntax will throws element property does not have an attribute value?